# unable to revert disc with iso, to a blank state

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, disc

I have a disc on which i put win 7 enterprise iso, I now have another version of windows which i need to install. I am attempting to revert the original to a blank disc so that the 2nd iso can be burnt to it.

i have been in the disk management and have reformatted the drive, but it is still showing the same amount of memory is being used on the disk, despite i when navigating to the disk no files are currently showing.

I have a feeling when the first iso was installed the disc was partitioned into a relative size that is less than the size of the disc.

I would post images but lack the reputation on this area of the site.

Comment: You're using the terms "disc" and "drive" in your question, so it's really hard to tell if you're referring to a hard drive on an optical disc.

From your question it seems like you're talking about a hard disk (since you mention partitioning of the disk), can you please confirm this?

Comment: dvd disc is what i mean. by drive it was the storage in Drive D: (my disc drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to be able to re-write a DVD, it must be a rewriteable DVD, also referred to as:

- DVD-RW
- DVD+RW
- DVD-RAM

which are different standards for rewriteable DVD-media. You can read more about the formats [here](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Hardware_Software/DVDFormatsExplained.asp)

What you're probably experiencing, is that your DVD media is a non-rewriteable media, which are called:

- DVD-R
- DVD+R

You will need to confirm which type of disc you have. If it's one of the 3 types in the top list, you need to go into your disc writing software of choice and erase the disc. If you dont have disc writing software, you could use (for example) [CDburnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/home), which is a Free utility, which runs on all modern versions of Windows.

When you have erased your disc, you can write your new ISO file to the disc and start using it.

Comment: i made assumptions that it was RW :/